# Basic conditional probability question

Tags: probability

$\sum_{c}p(a|c)p(c|b)=p(a|b)$. Does this equation hold true? If it is true, how to prove it mathematically?

Comment: You need to clarify what the summation with respect to $c$ is taken over.  Certainly not all such summations will give the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note quite right. The correct version is

$$\sum_{c}p(a|c\cap b)p(c|b)=p(a|b).$$

Proof:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{c}p(a|c\cap b)p(c|b) &=& \sum_{c}\dfrac{p(a\cap c\cap b)}{p(c\cap b)} \dfrac{p(c\cap b)}{p(b)} \\
&=& \sum_{c}\dfrac{p(a\cap c\cap b)}{p(b)} \\
&=& \dfrac{p(a\cap b)}{p(b)} \\
&=& p(a|b).
\end{eqnarray*}